# Python MemoryError in dictionary of millions of GeoNames locations?

Tags: python, memory, dictionary, pickle, geonames

I'm trying to create a dictionary of location names and information from Geonames to use in a program that reads documents, extracts location names, and outputs their information. Keys are location names and a list of tuples of the latitude and longitude, country code, feature class, and GeoName ID corresponding to each name (as there can be multiple locations with the same name) are values. Here's an example excerpt of the dictionary:

```
{'xixerella': [(('42.55327', '1.48736'), 'AD', 'PPL', '3038816'), (('42.55294', '1.48764'), 'AD', 'ADMD', '3038817')], 'fonts vives': [(('42.5', '1.56667'), 'AD', 'SPNG', '3038822')], 'roc del xeig': [(('42.56667', '1.48333'), 'AD', 'RK', '3038820')], 'costa de xurius': [(('42.5', '1.48333'), 'AD', 'SLP', '3038814')]}
```

The final dictionary has 9,088,105 keys. When I try to dump it into a file with pickle so I can reference it in my other program, it throws this error:

```
Python(763,0xa03871a8) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=50331648) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 31, in     <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1370, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 663, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 615, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 581, in save_tuple
    self.memoize(obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 247, in memoize
    self.memo[id(obj)] = memo_len, obj
MemoryError:
```

Is there a data structure I should be using instead of a dictionary? What can I do to cut down on memory usage?

This is my program as is:

```
import csv
import sys
import pickle

geodict = {}
ignore = ["", " ", "  ", "   ", "-", " -", "- ", " - "]
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
reader = csv.reader(open('allCountries-2.txt', 'rb'), delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
    loc = []
    loc.append(row[2].lower())
    if row[3] != '':
        altnames = row[3].split(',')
        for entry in altnames:
            entry = "".join(x for x in entry if ord(x)<128)
            entry = entry.lower()
            if entry not in loc:
                if entry not in ignore:
                    loc.append(entry)
    geoid = row[0]
    latlong = (row[4], row[5])
    feature = row[7]
    country = row[8]        
    for name in loc:
        if name in geodict:
            geodict[name].append((latlong, country, feature, geoid))
        else:
            geodict[name] = [(latlong, country, feature, geoid)]

with open('dict.txt', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(geodict, handle)
```

If you're unfamiliar with the format/contents of the Geonames file: it's a 1.14 GB tab delimited text file, row[2] is the location name in plain ASCII chars, row[3] is alternative location names (sometimes there are no alt names; I strip non-ASCII bc there are some crazy accented characters, Chinese/Japanese/etc characters that Python doesn't like). If anything else is unclear, just ask.

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When working with data structures that big, you should probably switch to [streaming pickle](https://code.google.com/p/streaming-pickle/). It works very similar manner to regular pickle, but load/saves in a streaming (incremental) manner, thus using far less memory.